# Testing simple typescript code in an Angular project from within VSCode

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an Angular project (version 15). My objective is to be able to test some simple Typescript code, which does not have any dependency on Angular, from within VSCode executing a single **spec** file from within VSCode.

When I develop a node project, I am used to create tests like this

```
describe(`a test suite`, () => {
  it(`test doStuff`, (done) => {
    const result = doStuff()
    const expectedResult = 'blah'
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
  });
});
```

and run them from within VSCode having the following **launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Current TS File - node",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": ["${relativeFile}"],
      "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register"],
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
    },
  ]
}
```

If I try to do the same with an Angular project, I end up with the following error

```
(node:81904) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
...
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Changing the **package.json** with `"type": "module"` does not sound a good idea and, in any case, generates a new error

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /.../test.spec.ts
```

Is there a way to test a typescript code, with no dependencies on Angular, from within VSCode as it is possible with Node?

Comment: There's an extension called Code Runner that you may find helpful.